# TypeError: this_obj.password_change_request is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been doing some research for this topic and the answers doesn't seem to help me.

I am trying to invoke a method with jquery's ajax callback and it doesn't seem to be working.

Its giving me the following error message

> TypeError: this_obj.password_change_request is not a function

Below is the code I am using:

```
function  resetPass() {

    // The following code validates the email text field and submit request for password change.
    function password_change_request(queryStr) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", url: "script/password_change_request.php",
            data: queryStr
        });
    }

    this.resetPassRequest = function () {
        $("#reset_password").click(function () {
            var this_obj  = this;
            var email_address = $("#email_reset").val();

            if (email_address == "") {
                return false;
            } else {
                var queryStr = "email=" + email_address + "&store=" + "<?=$store_dir_name?>";
                this_obj.password_change_request(queryStr);

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message is self-explaining. You have no `this_obj.password_change_request` function/method defined. Call `password_change_request()` instead.

Comment: Inside the click event handler `this` refers to the DOM element.

Comment: @hindmost. Yes you right. Thanks a lot!